# Program to calculate the number of zeros in an array

Tags: python

myArray = [1,0,2,4,5,10,4,0,3,0]
How to calculate the number of zeros in the the above array?

Comment: Have you tried `.count()` method?

Comment: Have you tried looking for similar questions in SO?

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
myArray = [1,0,2,4,5,10,4,0,3,0]

#Display the count of each value in the array
print(Counter(myArray))
```